# PHP Simple Math Results in Unexpected Result

Tags: php

I have two variables in a PHP program for billing statements,  $charges and $payments.

`$charges` is the total amount due before any payments. `$payments` is the total amount received.

I calculate the balance due like so:

```
$balance_due = $charges-$payments;
```

Simple, except I am getting the following result:

```
$balance_due has -9.0949470177293E-13 for a value (expecting 0).
```

Both $charges and $payments have a value of 5511.53.

When I `var_dump($charges)` and `var_dump($payments)` they both show: `float(5511.53)`

This code (and === ):

```
if($charges == $payments){
  error_log('they are the same');
}else{
  error_log('they are not the same');
}
```

both result in false.

If I hard code: $charges = $payments = 5511.53; and run it then $balance_due = 0 as expected.

I am confused.  What am I missing?

**EDIT NOTES**

I was able to use a user contributed function by Nitrogen found on the [BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) page that was suggested I look at in order to come up with the following solution:

```
if(Comp($charges, $payments)===0){
    $balance_due = 0;
}else{
    $balance_due = ( $charges - $payments );
}


function Comp($Num1,$Num2,$Scale=null) {
  // check if they're valid positive numbers, extract the whole numbers and decimals
  if(!preg_match("/^\+?(\d+)(\.\d+)?$/",$Num1,$Tmp1)||
     !preg_match("/^\+?(\d+)(\.\d+)?$/",$Num2,$Tmp2)) return('0');

  // remove leading zeroes from whole numbers
  $Num1=ltrim($Tmp1[1],'0');
  $Num2=ltrim($Tmp2[1],'0');

  // first, we can just check the lengths of the numbers, this can help save processing time
  // if $Num1 is longer than $Num2, return 1.. vice versa with the next step.
  if(strlen($Num1)>strlen($Num2)) return(1);
  else {
    if(strlen($Num1)<strlen($Num2)) return(-1);

    // if the two numbers are of equal length, we check digit-by-digit
    else {

      // remove ending zeroes from decimals and remove point
      $Dec1=isset($Tmp1[2])?rtrim(substr($Tmp1[2],1),'0'):'';
      $Dec2=isset($Tmp2[2])?rtrim(substr($Tmp2[2],1),'0'):'';

      // if the user defined $Scale, then make sure we use that only
      if($Scale!=null) {
        $Dec1=substr($Dec1,0,$Scale);
        $Dec2=substr($Dec2,0,$Scale);
      }

      // calculate the longest length of decimals
      $DLen=max(strlen($Dec1),strlen($Dec2));

      // append the padded decimals onto the end of the whole numbers
      $Num1.=str_pad($Dec1,$DLen,'0');
      $Num2.=str_pad($Dec2,$DLen,'0');

      // check digit-by-digit, if they have a difference, return 1 or -1 (greater/lower than)
      for($i=0;$i<strlen($Num1);$i++) {
        if((int)$Num1{$i}>(int)$Num2{$i}) return(1);
        else
          if((int)$Num1{$i}<(int)$Num2{$i}) return(-1);
      }

      // if the two numbers have no difference (they're the same).. return 0
      return(0);
    }
  }
}
```

That solution worked for me.  The answer provided by imtheman below also works and seems more efficient so I am going to use that one instead.  **Is there any reason not to use one or the other of these?**

Comment: Welcome to floating numbers. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison

Comment: Are you asking how to fix this? Or why does it happen?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point numbers, where accuracy is impossible and everything is approximated. You are essentially getting "0" - your value is 10 to the negative 13th, which is `0.0000000000000909494....`. for all intents and purposes it IS zero.

Comment: [BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) should be something to look into as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this problem when I ran into it was using php's `number_format()`. From [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
string number_format(float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ])
```

So what I would do is this:

```
$balance_due = number_format($charges-$payments, 2);
```

And that should solve your problem.

Note: `number_format()` will return a string, so to compare it you must use `==` (not `===`) or cast it back into a `(float)` before comparison.